# Progressbar not working inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am using an `AsyncTask` to download some big amount of data from a server my AsyncTask work fine so i added a progress bar to make everything beautiful but problem is when its running progress bar get freeze half way down, and i use progress dialog that also the same its freeze half way down,

```
private class downloadChannelsfromserver extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

     ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String data = "";

        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = getLinksfromServer(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
         progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(Settings.this, "Synchronicing","Synchronicing", true);


    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        JSONObject json;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(result);
            db.deleteAll();
            final JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("XXXX");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                ///use for insert datainto database
            }
            finish();

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("settings", "", e);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

can and someone tell me why this happen, Pls

Comment: Where are you updating the state of your progressbar?

Comment: Is the class downloadChannelsfromserver, is the inner class of Settings Activity?

Comment: try to dismiss your dialog before you call finish on activity
  finish();

            progressDialog.dismiss();
swap them around?

Comment: this just a simple progress dialog , yes this is a inner class or settings activity , i already swap them but still it freezing

Comment: Unless you add the code where you initialize and update your progressBar, I'm afraid noone will be able to help you accurately.

Comment: @NKN i added a progressdialog since the progressbar not working u can see where i am initializing the progress dialog problem is both these widgets get freeze when soon after its shows that is the problem and above code its one that i am using now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for progress bar get stuck was my `JSON` decoding since `onPostExecute` belongs to UI thread it take several time to decode the json results. so it will freeze the UI until JSON decode so move the decoding part to `doInBackground` will solve the UI freeze issue since `doInBackground` belongs to background thread

Answer (score 2):

Follow this code

```
private ProgressDialog pdialog = null;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() { 
   super.onPreExecute();

   if(pdialog ==null){
     //display progress dialog like this
     pdialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
     pdialog.setCancelable(false);
     pdialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
     pdialog.show();
   }
}



@Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //dismiss progress dialog like this

        if(pdialog!=null){
             pdialog.dismiss();
             pdialog = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please edit your code like this:

```
private class downloadChannelsfromserver extends
    AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

 ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public downloadChannelsfromserver()
{
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Settings.this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Synchronicing ...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
    String data = "";

    try {
        // Fetching the data from web service
        data = getLinksfromServer(url[0]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
    }
    return data;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onPreExecute();
  progressDialog.show();

}



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    JSONObject json;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(result);
        db.deleteAll();
        final JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("XXXX");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            ///use for insert datainto database
        }
        finish();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("settings", "", e);
    }
    finally
    {
     progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please share your Logcat logs, when your Progress Dialog gets frozen, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use This Code:

```kotlin
runOnUiThread(object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        pausingDialog =
            SweetAlertDialog(this@History_Activity, SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE)
        pausingDialog!!.titleText = "Please wait...."
        pausingDialog!!.setCancelable(false)
        pausingDialog!!.show()
    }
})

runOnUiThread(object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
    }
})
```